# Cohesive devices

Tags: pronouns

Hi I'm analysing an old advertisement at the moment. Below's a picture of it, [image: Chubbette and Trim-Teen advertisement]
I'm stumped on one thing. Can someone tell me if the pronouns 'you' and 'your' are anaphoric references or exophoric references? Because the headline of the advertisement has "welcome teacher" and  "Bring the children" Could the pronouns be referring to the teachers and children or only the readers?

Comment: It refers to "every girl," with which the actual narrative begins. Note the line 'you and **your mother**' later within the copy. Also, the products are named 'Chubbette' & 'Trim-Teen' meant for preteens and teens. 'Welcome Teachers' is a sideline, not the headline, and is to be read with an implied 'also.' 'No School (on) Friday, (so,) Bring the children' is also aimed at the teacher.

Comment: The whole ad is aimed at the parents, who actually hafta pay for the stuff; since it's girl's clothing, probably the mother. And the fashions are not just for preteens and teens, but for (those who are -- or can be convinced that they are) **overweight** preteens and teens. Note the invitees are urged to "Come and Meet" a (Male!) "Authority on Fashions for The Hard-to-Fit Girl and Teen-Ager". These are all euphemisms for "fat".

Comment: so basically 'you' and 'your' are anaphoric references right? Because they refer to every girl

Comment: @PriscillaTan Where's the *you* and *your* in there?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the *you* in "You and your mother" means "you, the hard-to-fit girl [or] teen-ager."

The advertisement is somewhat complicated by the fact that it makes scattershot appeals to multiple potential categories of readers, but that's because The Emporium is advertising not just its Trim-Teen and Chubbette lines of clothing (for the hard-to-fit girl and teen-ager) but its famous hats (for women) and its spring cottons (for people who know how to sew).

The phrases "Welcome Teachers" and "Bring the Children!" appear at the top of the advertisement—above the "Spring Fashion Trunk Show," "Famous Hat," and "Spring Cottons" subsections—and are addressed to adults who may or may not have any interest in the Trunk Show's Trim-Teen and Chubbette offerings.

I hadn't previously encountered the term "anaphoric reference," but *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines it as follows:

> **anaphoric** *adj* (1904) of or relating to anaphora {an *anaphoric* usage}; *esp* : being a word or phrase that takes its reference from another word or phrase and esp. from a preceding word or phrase

and to the extent that the *you* in "You and your mother" doesn't encompass every reader who looks at the ad, it does seem to refer to the preceding phrase "the hard-to-fit girl & teen-ager."

Comment: The question is somewhat flawed, as _anaphoric_ (‘referring back to something earlier in the text’) is not the opposite of _exophoric_ (‘referring to something extralinguistic not present in the text’). The oppositional pairs are _anaphoric_ <> _cataphoric_ (‘referring to something later in the text’), and _exophoric_ <> _endophoric_ (‘referring to something present in the text = ana- or cataphoric’). In this particular case, I agree that _you_ is anaphoric.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Merriam-Webster's explicitly refers readers of its definition of _anaphoric_ to the contrasting definition of _cataphoric_ (which includes as an example the phrase "before her Jane saw nothing but desert"), but it doesn't cover _endophoric_ and _exophoric_ at all. I get the impression that these may be relatively recently popularized terms; MW gives a first occurrence date of 1968 to _cataphoric_, though (as noted above) _anaphoric_ dates to 1904, and of course the rhetorical term _anaphora_ is much much older than that.